PostgreSQL & SQLAlchemy: plainto_tsquery with OR operator instead of AND operator
How can i take plain query from user and separate it with OR operator?
SELECT plainto_tsquery('english', 'user query');

output:
"'user' & 'queri'"

but i need something like that:
"'user' | 'queri'"

to_tsquery is not suitable for me, websearch_to_tsquery almost the same.
Also I'm using SQLAlchemy, maybe there is something that can help with it
